# XML or JSON reponse for Flex applications with PHP backend?

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex, json

I'm developing a floorplanner Flex mini application.  I was just wondering whether JSON or XML would be a better choice in terms of performance when generating responses from PHP.  I'm currently leaning for JSON since the responses could also be reused for Javascript.  I've read elsewhere that JSON takes longer to parse than XML, is that true?  What about flexibility for handling data with XML vs JSON in Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is not a native structure to Flex (strange, huh? You'd think that the {} objects could be easily serialized, but not really), XML is. This means that XML is done behind the scenes by the virtual machine while the JSON Strings are parsed and turned into objects through String manipulation (even if you're using AS3CoreLib)... gross... Personally, I've also seen inconsistencies in JSONEncoder (at one point Arrays were just numerically indexed objects).

Once the data has been translated into an AS3 object, it is still faster to search and parse data in XML than it is with Objects. XPath expressions make data traversal a pleasure (almost easy enough to make you smile compared to other things out there).

On the other hand JS is much better at parsing JSON. MUCH, MUCH BETTER. But, since the move to JavaScript is a "maybe... someday..." then you may want to consider, "will future use of JSON be worth the performance hit right now?"

But here is a question, why not simply have two outputs? Since both JS and AS can provide you POSTs with a virtually arbitrary number of variables, you really only need to concern yourself with how the server send the data not receives it. Here's a potential way to handle this:

```
 // as you are about to output:
 $type = './outputs/' . $_GET[ 'type' ] . '.php';
 if( file_exists( $type ) && strpos( $type, '.', 1 ) === FALSE )
 {
     include( $type );
     echo output_data( $data );
 }
 else
 {
     // add a 404 if you like 
     die();
 }
```

Then, when getting a $_GET['type'] == 'js', js.php would be:

```
 function output_data( $data ){ return json_encode( $data ); }
```

When getting  $_GET['type'] == 'xml', xml.php would hold something which had output_data return a string which represented XML (plenty of examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php))

Of course, if you're using a framework, then you could just do something like this with a view instead (my suggestion boils down to "you should have two different views and use MVC").

Comment: @Peter If it really is that simple, then you probably are better off using JSON all around -- the only time JSON really becomes an issue with AS3 is with extremely large data sets.

Comment: I'm not sure where the threshold is for speed. Benchmark if you're uncertain.

Comment: Using an home made JSON parser (because AS2 don't prove JSON yet...),I can parse ~30k lines in less than 1sec with a JSON but it takes 30sec with XML... also, XML is way to verbose, 4times bigger in data transfer, when you 've reached the Mo limits, this is not negligeable ;)

Comment: @AxelH AS3 doesn't support JSON either.... You shouldn't be using a home made parser, there is a lib for that already (or there was one at one point, haven't touched that stack in a while). But even if there weren't, I'd wonder about the verbosity of your test -- XML has more data, but it's much faster to traverse inside of AS (XPath and all that), and the code has a smaller footprint.

Comment: This app is a basic management data, so I only recover some list to insert into dataprovider (combobox or datagrid). I found the as3corelib that contains the Json decoder so I don't use mine anymore (but he worked fine!). I still have huge diff in decoding 7 Mo of data. Since I don't need/use the XML advantage (XPATH...) the Json seems the best choice...

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with JSON. We've added native JSON support to Flash Player, so it will be as fast on the parsing side as XML and it's much less verbose/smaller.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

No, JSON is ALWAYS smaller than XML when their structures are completely same. And the cost of parsing text is almost up to the size of the target text.

So, JSON is faster than XML and if you have a plan to reuse them on javascript side, choose JSON.

Benchmark JSON vs XML:
http://www.navioo.com/ajax/ajax_json_xml_Benchmarking.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're ever going to use Javascript with it, definitely go with JSON.  Both have a very nice structure.

It depends on how well Flex can parse JSON though, so I would look into that.  How much data are you going to be passing back?  Error/Success messages? User Profiles?  What kind of data is this going to contain?

Is it going to need attributes on the tags? Or just a "structure".  If it needs attributes and things like that, and you don't want to go too deep into an "array like" structure, go with XML.

If you're just going to have key => value, even multi-dimensional... go with JSON.

All depends on what kind of data you're going to be passing back and forth.  That will make your decision for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Download time:**

JSON is faster.

**Javascript Parse**

JSON is faster

**Actionscript Parse**

XML is faster.

**Advanced use within Actionscript**

XML is better with all the E4X functionality.
JSON is limited with no knowledge of Vectors meaning you are limited to Arrays or will need to override the JSON Encoder in ascorelib with something such as

```
else if ( value is Vector.<*> ) {
    // converts the vector to an array and
    return arrayToString( vectorToArray( value ) );
} else if ( value is Object && value != null ) {



private function vectorToArray(__vector:Object):Array {
    var __return    : Array;
    var __vList     : Vector.<*>;

    __return = new Array;

    if ( !__vector || !(__vector is Vector.<*>) )
    {
        return __return;
    }

    for each ( var __obj:* in (__vector as Vector.<*>) )
    {
        __return.push(__obj);
    }

    return __return;
}
```

But I am afraid getting those values back into Vectors is not as nice. I had to make a whole utility class devoted to it.

So which one is all depending on how advanced your objects you are going to be moving.. More advanced, go with XML to make it easier ActionScript side.
Simple stuff go JSON